# Simple probabilty / set problem I would love an explanation to.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am currently studying som very elementary set theory in my algebra text book and I just arrived at this problem (I am a beginner in this so please bear with me):

*Question:* In a specific situation there are $100$ people. At least $70$% of these lose an eye, at least $75$% lose an ear, at least $80$% lose an arm and at least $85$% lose a leg. How many (at least) does get sick and get all four of the symptoms?

*Answer:* One way to go about this would be to calculate the chance of each of these "symptoms" to happen that would be: $0.70 * 0.75 * 0.80 * 0.85$ which is: $0.357$ or $35.7%.$%

Then there should be atleast **$35$ people** that suffers from all of the symptoms above.

The other way to do this is to say that all people are $|U| = 100$ and the symptoms are the sets $A, B, C$ and $D$. We then have $|A| \geq 70$, $|B| \geq 75$, $|C| \geq 80$, $|D| \geq 85$.

According to this formula: $A_1 \cap ...  \cap A_n = |A_1|+ ... +|A_n| - (n-1)|U|$

We get: $A  \cap B  \cap C  \cap D \geq |A| + |B| + |C| + |D| - 3|U| \geq 70 + 75 + 80 + 85 - 300 = 10$

This means that at least $10$% of all people got all symptoms which can be translated to at least **$10$ people**.

Why is there such a large discrepancy between these two results? If anyone can explain that to me I would be very happy!

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first method doesn't really calculate the least number with all 4 ailments; it calculates the exact number, but on the assumption that the ailments are independent of each other. The second method makes no assumption of independence, and really does calculate the least number.

Try it with 2 ailments, where things aren't so complicated, it will be easier to see what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

set-theoretic approach gives the lower bound in the 'worst' case possible in your situation (where worst means that there are as few as possible people with all four diseases) - although you should probably check that again, because your answer can't be true - you can have exactly 70 people lose an eye which is in contradiction with your answer

probabilistic approach deals with somehow 'averaging' the situation. it doesn't deal with one particular case, it deals with *all* possible cases therefore it says something like "if you had a lot of samples of hundreds of people of such population then the percentage of people having all the disesases will be close to $35\%$ (very vague interpretation, I know). also - your approach isn't exactly right either, because you took the chance of getting a symptom to be exactly the lower bound given in the problem while it's not said that *exactly* $x\%$ suffer from a given condition.

here's another example you might want to consider. suppose that there's a $1\%$ chance of winning a free beer in a lottery and you have $1,000,000$ people playing it. probabilistic approach tells us, that the number of winners should be close to $10,000$ but it might happen that noone wins if they're all unlucky - that's possible, but has a very very small probability, yet still has to be considered in the deterministic case in set-theoretic approach

hope it's understandable and helps you somehow